# three.js mouseover on object only not background

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I am new to Three.js. I am trying to show tooltip on cubes/blocks only  for that I am successful with the help of this link http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Tooltip.html If you see the tooltip changes the color and text on background(checkboxes) as well. I don't want that. I only want to show tooltip on the cubes.

Also, what would be the possible way to show html tags in the tooltip? As you cannot insert html tags in

```
context1.fillText( '<h1>Hello World</h1>', 4,20 );
```

I also tried to implement jQuery tooltips moving towards the mouse pointer but all in vain.

I would really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the highlight colors, remove lines 192-194 and 197-200:

```
// restore previous intersection object (if it exists) to its original color
if ( INTERSECTED ) 
    INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
```

and

```
// store color of closest object (for later restoration)
INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
// set a new color for closest object
INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xffff00 );
```

In addition, to have better label customization options, I have written a different demo that you may want to consider at: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Sprite-Text-Labels.html -- if you want to insert HTML tags to format the font (as it appears you do), instead consider drawing text on a canvas, and on the canvas you can set options like font family, size, weight, etc., and then use the canvas as the image for your tooltip. Again, to see a working implementation of the code, please see the link above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It removes highlighted color from cubes too, and I want to remove color only from the background.

Comment: Also, I want to add html tags in the tooltip for certain information like an image along with some links(<a href="">) and line breaks. Is there a way I can do that?